# PostgreSQL : how do I make this sum

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0

I have this huge table with all the addresses of my country in it. Every house is an object, and  there is a column for the streetname (or street ID) and a column for the housenumber.
I want to make a new table with all the street-id's in it, and the sum of houses on that street, what is the fastest way to make this calculation ?

Thanks

Comment: This is a simple aggregation SQL query. Furthermore, at first glance, there isn't anything specific to GIS here. What have you tried so far? where are you stuck?

Answer (score 8):

Assuming your data table look like:

```
streetid    housenumber
100         12
100         15
101         12
101         18
```

You could do a basic SQL query:

```
SELECT streetid, count(*) FROM tablename GROUP BY streetid
```

Where this might get more GIS-y and interesting is the case where streets with the same ID are not contiguous. You didn't mention if this is a PostGIS database, but if it is and you have a `geom` column then you'll probably want to split multipart into singlepart geometries using [`ST_Dump`](http://amercader.net/blog/2011/04/exploding-multigeometries-with-postgis).